# Deleting cookies and history without user intervention

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, history, cookies

I am looking for a clickless solution for deleting cookies in Chrome or Firefox. Basically deleting cookies and history without my intervention. For example, every time a selected website gets visited or closed, I want to delete cookies and history.

Can this be done somehow? I am on a mac.

Comment: You might want to use the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) to avoid being tracked.

Comment: You might also want to use Incognito and Private modes if you do not want cookies and history to be retained on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to use "Private Browsing" on Firefox (ctrl-shift-P), or "Incognito Mode" on Chrome (Ctrl-Shift-N). This session will not remember:

- History
- Searches
- Cookies
- Temporary Files

If privacy is your true concern beyond the Private/Incognito mode, then check everything on that [privacytools](https://www.privacytools.io/) page  and specifically https://www.privacytools.io/#about_config page for firefox config recommendation.

The relevant note that you want (clickless cookie deletion):

> go to about:config 
>  network.cookie.lifetimePolicy = 2 
>  cookies are deleted at the end of the session 
>   2 = Accept for current session only

Hope this helps.